# ament_cmake_clang_format fails to find ament_clang_format package

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to include the ament_clang_format test in my CMakeLists.txt file.

I have tried using ament_lint_auto

package.xml

```
    <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

    <depend>builtin_interfaces</depend>
    <depend>rosidl_default_generators</depend>

    <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
    <!-- <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend> -->
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_copyright</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_cppcheck</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_cpplint</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_flake8</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_lint_cmake</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_pep257</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_xmllint</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_clang_format</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_uncrustify</test_depend>
    <test_depend>ament_cmake_gtest</test_depend>

    <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

    <export>
        <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
    </export>
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
if(BUILD_TESTING)
    # linters
    find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
    # find_package(ament_clang_format REQUIRED)
    ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()
```

which fails on build (I have ros2 installed and built from source @ /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base)

```
    CMake Error at /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_clang_format/share/ament_cmake_clang_format/cmake/ament_cmake_clang_format-extras.cmake:19 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_clang_format/share/ament_cmake_clang_format/cmake/ament_cmake_clang_format.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_clang_format/share/ament_cmake_clang_format/cmake/ament_cmake_clang_formatConfig.cmake:38 (include)
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_lint_auto/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies.cmake:35 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:48 (ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies)


CMake Error at /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_clang_format/share/ament_cmake_clang_format/cmake/ament_cmake_clang_format_lint_hook.cmake:27 (ament_clang_format):
  Unknown CMake command "ament_clang_format".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:38 (include)
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_lint_auto/share/ament_lint_auto/cmake/ament_lint_auto_package_hook.cmake:15 (ament_execute_extensions)
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:38 (include)
  /root/ros2_ws/ros2_base/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_package.cmake:66 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:64 (ament_package)


make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

If I use the following in the package.xml

```
<test_depend>ament_cmake_clang_format</test_depend>
```

as per https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/blob/master/ament_cmake_clang_format/doc/index.rst the test simply does not run.

I CAN, however, run the test from the command line

```
root@C001721433:~/ros2_ws/ros2_ov# ament_clang_format
No code style divergence in file 'test/test_msg.cpp'

No errors
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317464/ament_cmake_clang_format-fails-to-find-ament_clang_format-package/) by [Maxx](https://answers.ros.org/users/37966/maxx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the CMake code of the `ament_cmake_clang_format` package tries to include the wrong CMake file. Please see https://github.com/ament/ament_lint/pull/128 for a proposed fix.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maxx](https://answers.ros.org/users/37966/maxx/) on 2019-03-05**:
This fixed the issue, thanks!